# How to smoothly move GMSMarker along coordinates in Objective c

Tags: objective-c, google-maps

I'm using google map sdk. I want to update gps coordinates of pin after each 5 seconds. Currently I'm just updating position attribute of GMSMarker. But it gives jump effect. I want to move marker smoothly on map.
Here is my code to update position of marker

```
-(void)updateLocationoordinates(CLLocationCoordinate2D) coordinates
{ 
  if (marker == nil) {
      marker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:coordinates];
      marker.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:CAR_FOUND_IMAGE];
      marker.map = mapView_;
  } else
  marker.position = coordinates; 
}
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Change your else block to be something more like this:

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setAnimationDuration:2.0];
marker.position = coordindates;
[CATransaction commit];
```

We enable you to use [Core Animation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coreanimation_guide/introduction/introduction.html) for animating Google Maps.

For a worked sample, please see `AnimatedCurrentLocationViewController.{c,m}` in the SDK sample application.

Comment: Thank you @Brett. I updated the google sdk then these animations worked fine.

Comment: For me, this actually didn't work.  In fact, it completely broke animation of the .position property.  The good news is that is *exactly* what I wanted: a way to turn off the animation of the .position property.  Thanks a ton!  For reference, I set the animation duration to 0.0, but having a non-0 value still didn't animate.

Comment: OK - I lied.  It works exactly as the poster mentions.  I'd just screwed up my test.  I noticed it too late to edit my first comment, however.

Comment: Can anyone send code snippet to  animate polyline of google maps.

Comment: @Sadia can you tel mel how did you achieve this?

Comment: @Brett .. How can i do this in swift

Comment: @UmaMadhavi the syntax for using Core Animation from Swift is covered in Apple's documentation. Here's a [starting point](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/CoreAnimationBasics/CoreAnimationBasics.html).

Comment: @Brett, I have used this animation and it work really good. Thanks & vote up. But i see a problem which i mentioned on this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41060922/gmsmarker-bouncing-around-the-corners-on-gmspolyline . can you help me in achieving animation in this situation. I have the coordinates around the corner that user has skipped. But i cant find appropriate animation which can animate on those missed points. I tried Blocks on CATransaction , CAAnimation, Basic Key frame but do not find an appropriate one.

Comment: i ask what @KumarSwamy asked can anyone please share the code snippet for animating polylines

Answer (score 1):

Brett's Answer in swift -3 and 4

```
CATransaction.begin()
CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(2.0)
marker.position = coordindates
CATransaction.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

just Initialize marker in view did load and  update it when you want to do it no need of any kind of animation like

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    ..write code here
        marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
}
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([latitudue doubleValue], [longitude doubleValue]);
```