# How to move marker with animation from one location to another smoothly in google map ios

Tags: ios, google-maps

Created marker like below based on latitudes and longitudes help me to move marker to another location with animation.

```
GMSMarker *marker1 = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
marker1.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(12.9716, 77.5946);
marker1.title = @"Bangalore";
marker1.groundAnchor = CGPointMake(0.2, 0.9);
marker1.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop;
marker1.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Flag Filled -50.png"];
marker1.snippet = @"India";
marker1.map = _mapView;
```

Comment: possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19115293/how-to-smoothly-move-gmsmarker-along-coordinates-in-objective-c

Answer (score 7):

**Using  Xcode 9 Swift 4 : Moving markers smoothly.**

```
@objc func moveMarker(){
    self.lat += 0.0017
    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setValue(2.0, forKey: kCATransactionAnimationDuration)
    CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
        self.marker.groundAnchor = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    }
    self.mapView.animate(to: GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: self.lat, longitude: self.lon, zoom: 15))
    self.marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: self.lat, longitude: self.lon)
    CATransaction.commit()
    self.marker.map = self.mapView
}
```

Your Marker will move on Map like Uber's Car on map.

It is not necessary to mention `.groundAnchor` property, Read Google Docs for that.

Also, Update the `self.lat` and `self.lon` before passing the values in `CATransaction`. ( `lat` and `lon` are Global variable with default value)

Lastly I've used `Timer.scheduledTimer` to call

```
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
       var timer = Timer()
       timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(moveMarker), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
```

I bet it'll will help some one. =)

**Result :**

[image]

Comment: You can add marker rotation and bearing according to how your backend is sending coordinates, Bearing angle etc.

Comment: I think your animation interval should be less than timer interval ....

Answer (score 0):

You can use setRotation method of GMSMarker.Hope it will work.

Comment: Set rotation makes marker to rotate  by some degrees..but i need to move  marker from one lacation to another.thanks for the help

Comment: Please once look at setPosition and pass lat long and again fitMap.

Comment: That changes the marker position but i need to animate from old location to new based on lat long values.