# How to disable animation for changing GMSMarker position in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

According to [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_marker) you can change marker position with animation:

> Marker position.
>   Animated.

Do you know how to disable this animation?

Comment: Its somewhat a hack. Check my answer

Answer (score 7):

Suppose your reference for marker is `mainMarker` which is a `GMSMarker` object

```
var mainMarker:GMSMarker?
```

And suppose this is your function to change marker position without animation

```
func changeMarkerWithoutAnimation() {
    mainMarker?.map = nil
    mainMarker = nil
    let changedPosition = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(22.9734, 78.6569)
    mainMarker = GMSMarker(position: changedPosition)
    mainMarker?.title = "Hello World"
    mainMarker!.map = mapView
}
```

This will change your marker's position without animation.

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari..  I want to move my marker with my updated coordinates .How can i achieve this.

Comment: @UmaMadhavi This is just creating a new marker with updated coordinates without animation. You can simply use `CoreAnimation` to achieve this and not making your marker nil. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/19128891/2545465
Even the google maps also provide a method `markerWithPosition:` for that purpose

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari.. yes, but i didn't understand that one.

Comment: @UmaMadhavi Its simple, first of all where you get your coordinates, may be in `didUpdateLocation`. Wherever you get, animate the marker towards your new coordinates. Just provide marker the new coords and I guess by default it animates to that position in Google Maps

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari.yes i want to add custom image for example car & i want to rotate that car icon not the default one.

Comment: @UmaMadhavi There is a property in `GMSMarker` called `rotation`. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_marker.html#abaa6d5cd12a00dad6388019f7913ebf7.
If you want to change the default marker image you can set a custom icon, using the marker's `icon` or `iconView` property.
Read the documentation. Everything is there.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/marker

Answer (score 4):

As implemented in google maps samples, you should use `CATransaction` for this purpose.

```
let changedPosition = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(22.9734, 78.6569)
CATransaction.begin()
CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(0.0)
marker.position = changedPosition
CATransaction.commit()
```

[Source](https://github.com/googlemaps/maps-sdk-for-ios-samples/blob/ed7cf07311584c7cf4d9e4fe9f4a55cf202afaec/GoogleMaps/GoogleMapsDemos/Samples/AnimatedCurrentLocationViewController.m#L94) demo.

Comment: This answer works well. In my case the answer provided by Rajan introduces a drawing bug in the Google Maps SDK where targets are not always updated.

Answer (score 1):

Another dirty and hacky workaround without recreating the marker:

```
extension GMSMarker
{
    func moveWithoutAnimation(_ newPosition: CLLocationCoordinate2D)
    {
        guard let map = map else {
            return
        }

        let oldPoint = map.projection.point(for: position)
        let newPoint = map.projection.point(for: newPosition)
        let delta = CGPoint(x: newPoint.x - oldPoint.x, y: newPoint.y - oldPoint.y)
        let width = iconView?.width ?? icon?.size.width ?? 26
        let height = iconView?.height ?? icon?.size.height ?? 41
        let deltaInPercentage = CGPoint(x: 0.5 - delta.x/width, y: 0.5 - delta.y/height)

        groundAnchor = deltaInPercentage
    }
}
```

Note, that actual `marker.position` won't change.